# Error al establecer valor a una propiedad de un objeto en una extension de Firefox

Tags: javascript, firefox, firefox-webextensions

Estoy intentando cambiar el valor de la propiedad `referrer` del objeto `document` en una extension de Firefox con el siguiente codigo

```
//Test.js
  Object.defineProperty(document, "referrer", {
   get: function() {
     return "Test"
   },
   set: function(a){},
     configurable: false
  })
```

Manifest.json

```
  {
     "manifest_version": 2,
     "name": "Test addon",
     "version": "beta",
     "description": "Spoofing browser data",
          "content_scripts": [
        {
          "matches": ["<all_urls>"],
          "js": ["test.js"],
          "run_at": "document_start"
        }
      ]
    }
```

Incluso intente con `document.referrer=""` pero no funciona, si ejecuto otro tipo de codigo como el tipico ejemplo `document.body.style.border='1px solid red'` funciona.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

La propiedad referrer del objeto document es una propiedad que se informa con el valor del de la cabecera HTTP llamada "referer" (Una erre menos).

Dicha cabecera es una cabecera prohibida, esto es, un valor que el navegador te va a dejar cambiar de forma programática. Más info: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Forbidden_header_name

Aún así, puedes hacer algo así:

```js
console.log(document.referrer);
Object.defineProperty(document, "referrer", {get : function(){ return "PRUEBA"; }});
console.log(document.referrer);
```

Más info en este hilo: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9580575/how-to-manually-set-referer-header-in-javascript,